# Setting enctype attribute for mixed data types, including file

Tags: php, html, post, file-upload, enctype

I am new to PHP and HTML, and have trouble understanding the enctype attribute of the form when using POST. In all examples of File Upload using PHP, it is written that I should set enctype as multipart/form-data (which, as far as I understand, is used for files). However in all these examples, the only input on the form is file input.

My question is, what if I want to have form with mixed inputs? Particularly, both text and file. Then, if I set enctype to multipart/form-data, will I still be able to access both files and text from PHP using $_FILES and $_POST?

Thank you

Comment: Why not try it yourself?

Comment: I've seen some posts saying that this way I cannot get data from $_POST. For ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075513/php-parsing-multipart-form-data

Comment: enctype is used when your form contains file input if your form do not have file input there is no need of it. You will get values in $_FILES only if enctype is added in your form. Don't Worry about $_POST you can access your all values using it apart from file input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `multipart/form-data`.

It converts each piece of data to a part in a multi-part MIME request (and then does some specific encoding of each part). It isn't just for files, and if you are using PHP then `$_POST` will be populated normally.

The alternative (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) basically builds a query string. For a POST request it makes that query string the request body. This format doesn't have any provision for encoding files.

Answer (score 1):

It basically means, add the $_FILE array to the request. For more information, read this question 
[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)